# why under v-row and v-col vuetify always align center

Tags: vuetify.js

can any body help, why in vuetify under v-col always align center ?
i try to make simple paragraph, but why always align center ?

here is my code

```
<v-container>
    <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" md="8">
            <p>test paragraph</p>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" md="4">
            <p>test kedua</p>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>    
</v-container>
```

Comment: No, by default it does not center the text ( default is align-left ). Verify your CSS because `text-align` is an inherited property.

Comment: oh ok, i find it css in app.vue